# Do ATMs at banks in Mexico generally require cards with chips?

Tags: payment-cards, mexico, atms

Do ATMs at banks in Mexico generally require cards with chips to withdraw cash?

Comment: Do any cash machines anywhere require chips? Part of the reason your chip-and-pin card still has a mag-stripe is so you can still use the card if the chip fails.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm pretty sure most Korean ATMs only process chip-based transactions and the magstripe fallback has been switched off. I don't know of another place but other countries will probably follow at some point.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ask your bank if they allow non-EMV transactions, as it is the bank that will refuse the transaction and not the ATM.

All ATMs since the 70s/80s are equipped with the mag stripe readers, and most ATMs have been upgraded to accept mag stripe and EMV cards. So its not the ATM that will reject your card, it is your bank.

You run the risk of automatic rejection if you have a non-EMV card and are using it at a kiosk or vending machine, as these are high risk devices and thus have more stringent controls.

Comment: If the bank has issued a card that's mag-stripe only, I seriously doubt they will refuse to honor it at an ATM, if the ATM accepts it.

Comment: If the ATM ha no cash, or no connection to contact the bank, or the card is canceled, then it isn't the bank rejecting the card, it's the ATM.

Answer (score 0):

I have used both my mag-stripe only card and my chip card this year in Peru, Mexico, Spain, England, Wales, Ireland, and USA.  Last year in Canada, Mexico, and Iceland.  2014 in Netherlands and Turkey.  Someday, they'll stop accepting mag-stripe, but not yet.  You might ask your bank why they are taking so long to make the switch.